# The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am trying to extend the IdentityUser class. I added a new class ApplicationUser and inherit IdentityUser class. Migration is added successfully but on updating database, I am getting the error "The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.". I opened the SSMS and looked for data in AspNetUserToken, the table was empty.

a couple of things I have tried but end up with the same error. I replaced all the references to the IdentityUser class in my code. Delete the data in table 'AspNetUsers'. Remove the migration after replacing references and deleting data. Again added migration and update database, the error was still there.

```
AppDbContext.cs


namespace PieShop.Data_Access_Layer
{
    public class AppDbContext :IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            :base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Pie> Pies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
    }
}


IdentityHostingStartup.cs


[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(PieShop.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace PieShop.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
ApplicationUser.cs


namespace PieShop.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address  { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Migration

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace PieShop.Migrations
{
    public partial class ApplicationUserAdded : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Address",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "City",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            maxLength: 30,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Country",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            maxLength: 20,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ProviderKey",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Address",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "City",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Country",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ProviderKey",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not reproduce , could you please provide detailed steps to help reproduce ?

Comment: I am using asp.net core 2.2 along with entity framework core and identity core. I started from empty project templet and set required middlewares to work with entity-framework, static files, and identity. I register some user's with default identify user class and after that, I extended the IdentityUser class and made the migration. Migration was successful but when I updated the database the update database was failed with this ERROR mentioned above.

Comment: Solved this problem by deleting the database and rollback migrations until the identity was added. after this, I added migration with ApplicationUser class (extended from identityUser class) and the fields in ApplicationUser class added successfully in AspNetUser table.

Comment: You are changing the UserId from max length from 450 to 128 characters.  Because of the primary and foreign key constraints you cannot.  It seems to me, it is an issue with *migrationBuilder.AlterColumn* not handling the two keys.  If I were to do this in SSMS, I would need to drop all PK and FK that reference UserId before making the change to all columns.  Unfortunately, your solution didn't solve my issue.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for you but after this, my issue was resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it by editing the migration and adding drop and add commands for the Primary Key.

At the top of the new migration, add:

```cs
migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", "AspNetUserTokens");
```

and after all modifications to `AspNetUserTokens` have taken place, add

```cs
migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", "AspNetUserTokens", new[] { "UserId", "LoginProvider", "Name" });
```

Comment: manipulating the generated migration this way worked for me as well. But is there a "cleaner" way to solve this kind of misalignment, perhaps via mapping in the DbContext class?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and solved this problem by

1-Delete Database and Migrations:
First, I deleted my database and all existing migrations. This ensured a clean slate to work with.

2-Recreate Database and Migrations:
Then, I rebuilt the database and migrations from scratch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).